# big text in title and trailing

Tags: flutter, dart

My code prints device characteristics. But if the text is too long, then the text is displayed ugly(as in the photo 1). I tried to fix it in different ways, but only title changes for me, trailing remains unchanged.
Can it be done in this way, if the text is long, then title is displayed in one line, and the next trailing (as in the photo 2)?

```
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
child: Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 800),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
            ),
              child: Card(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                        title: const Text('Brand:', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 25)),
                        trailing: Text('${device.brand} ', style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 20 ))),
                    const Divider(color: Colors.black, endIndent: 10, indent: 10),
                    ListTile(
                        title: const Text('Operation system:', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 25)),
                        trailing: Text('${device.operation_system} ', style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 20 ))),
                    const Divider(color: Colors.black, endIndent: 10, indent: 10),
                    ListTile(
                        title: const Text('Version of OS:', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 25)),
                        trailing: Text('${device.version_OS} ', style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 20 ))),
                    const Divider(color: Colors.black, endIndent: 10, indent: 10),
                    ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
      ]
          )
    )
)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to remove `trailing` from `ListTile` and use `RichText` and `TextSpan` for `title` like so:

```
ListTile(
  title: RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
      children: [
        const TextSpan(
          text: 'Version of OS: ',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            fontSize: 25,
          ),
        ),
        TextSpan(
          text: '${device.version_OS}',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: i have error "Invalid constant value." device underline red

Comment: Oops my fault! I've updated my answer to remove `const` from the `children` and instead added it to the first `TextSpan`

Comment: Yes, that's cool, thanks. But is it possible to make the second TextSpan {device.version_OS} by default adjacent to the right edge?

Comment: otherwise, if the text is short, then this parameter follows immediately after the colon. I would like it to fit to the right edge, like the rest of the parameters in the photo.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

```
     Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Text(
              'Version of OS',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontSize: 20,
                overflow:TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),),
            title: Text('Your version with version 1.0'),
            trailing: Text('Nokia'),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]